# find only same value of that closest to the current index element in an array dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

I have an array that have same value, so i want to like filter it only for same value that closest to the current index, example :

```
A[0] = 2, 
A[1] = -2, 
A[2] = -2, 
A[3] = 9, 
A[4] = 9,
A[5] = 9, 
A[6] = 4, 
A[7] = -2,
A[8] = -2,
A[9] = -2,
```

i want my code can find that the index `1` `2` is have same value which is `-2` with length `2`,
index `3` `4` `5` have same value `9` with length `3`
and index `7` `8` `9` have same value `-2` with length `3` and my code will return only the length of the most in the same value range and closest to index `0` which is value `9`

```
 void main() {
  var nInt = <ArrayA>[
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: 2),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -2),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -2),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: 9),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: 9),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: 9),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -1),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: 7),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -2),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -2),
    ArrayA(e: 'A', n: -2),


  for (var i = 0; i < nInt.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nInt.length; j++) {
      if (nInt[j].n == nInt[i].n) {
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  ];

class ArrayA {
  final String e;
  final int n;

  ArrayA({this.e, this.n});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? What is your expected output ?

Comment: @MidhunMP i have edited my questions, please review it,

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-order to achieve that, you need to store the comparison result and nearest index somewhere. For this purpose you can create a class like:

```dart
class Counter {
  final int index;
  final int number;
  final int count;

  Counter({required this.index, required this.number, required this.count});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$count times $number at $index';
  }
}
```

And change the logic to:

```dart
var counterValues = <Counter>[];
for (var i = 0; i < nInt.length; i++) {
   int count = 1;
   int value = nInt[i].n;
   for (var j = i + 1; j < nInt.length; j++) {
      if (nInt[j].n == nInt[i].n) {
         count += 1;
      } else {
         // Break the inner loop and go to next outer-loop iteration
         // You can optimise this by skipping already checked positions (ie: Update i)
         break;
      }
   }
   counterValues.add(Counter(index: i, count: count, number: value));
}
```

And finally to find the most recurring nearest value, you can use the [reduce](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.13.0-184.0.dev/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html):

```dart
var result =
      counterValues.reduce((a, b) => (a.count >= b.count && a.index < b.index) ? a : b);
print(result); // Output: 3 times 9 at 3
```

Comment: thankyou so much, i've been stuck for like 3 days since my app needed a new method condition, Thank you so much